# addEventListener ('click', ...) By clicking on 'numbers' button text on the display should be equal to that number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a javascript calculator as per freecodecamp requirement on front end track.

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/ekilja01/pen/MoXROe

By pressing any number on calculator the display must be changed to that number. Also the var number has to remember its value, because by clicking the number again it becomes a new number, so after that I can use operators and parseInt to evaluate and display the final value.  I've got an idea how can this be implemented by using jQuery, so something like this:

```
   $("#numbers a").not("#clear,#clearall").click(function(){
        number += $(this).text();
        totaldiv.text(number);

    });
    $("#operators a").not("#equals").click(function(){
        operator = $(this).text();
        newnumber = number;
        number = "";
        totaldiv.text("0");
    });
    $("#clear,#clearall").click(function(){
        number = "";
        totaldiv.text("0");
        if ($(this).attr("id") === "clearall") {
            newnumber = "";
        }
    });
    //Add your last .click() here!
    $("#equals").click(function(){
        if (operator === "+"){
            number = (parseInt(number, 10) + parseInt(newnumber,10)).toString(10);
        } else if (operator === "-"){
            number = (parseInt(newnumber, 10) - parseInt(number,10)).toString(10);
        } else if (operator === "÷"){
            number = (parseInt(newnumber, 10) / parseInt(number,10)).toString(10);
        } else if (operator === "×"){
            number = (parseInt(newnumber, 10) * parseInt(number,10)).toString(10);
        }
        totaldiv.text(number);
        number = "";
        newnumber = "";
    });
```

But what can be equivalent to this in vanilla js? I've tried .textContent or .innerHTML, but neither of them work. On calculator's dispay either undefined or `<a>1</a>` ... `<a>AC</a>`. Also what is the equivalent to .not(). Any help will be much appreciated.

**html**:

```
<div id="calculator">
          <p id="cal">CALCULATOR</p>
          <div id="total">
          </div>
          <div id="operators">
              <a>&divide;</a>
              <a>&times;</a>
              <a>+</a>
              <a>-</a>
              <a>=</a>
          </div>
          <div id="numbers">
              <a>1</a>
              <a>2</a>
              <a>3</a>
              <a>4</a>
              <a>5</a>
              <a>6</a>
              <a>7</a>
              <a>8</a>
              <a>9</a>
              <a id="clear">C</a>
              <a>0</a>
              <a id="clearall">AC</a>
          </div>
      </div>
```

**js**:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
    console.log('DOM OK');

    // Declare variables for number, new number and operators

    var number, newNumber, operator = "";

    // Declare variable total number to display total on the calculator's display

    var totalNumber = document.getElementById("total");
    totalNumber.textContent = "0";



    document.getElementById("numbers").addEventListener('click', function(){
        number += this.textContent;
        totalNumber.textContent = number;
    })

})
```

Comment: `.innerText` is the regular js version.  `innerHTML` would grab all markup, so you don't want that.

Comment: Your selector for events is on the parent `#numbers`, when the number values you want to access live inside of its children — the `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use the event argument in the callback function. For example:

```
 number  = "";

document.getElementById("numbers").addEventListener('click', function(e){
    number += e.target.textContent;
    totalNumber.textContent = number;
})
```

More information on the event target properties specifically:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Entire JS code:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
 console.log('DOM OK');

// Declare variables for number, new number and operators

var number, newNumber, operator = "";

// Declare variable total number to display total on the calculator's display

var totalNumber = document.getElementById("total");
totalNumber.textContent = "0";



number  = "";

document.getElementById("numbers").addEventListener('click', function(e){
 number += e.target.textContent;
 totalNumber.textContent = number;
})

})
```

Comment: Edited my response to include all the code used to get a working example. Please note, I had to add the first line (setting number to empty string) to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I have declared a number variable and assigned a value of an empty string to it at the end of my script, however you s is still doesn't work. All I have is undefined + number on the display.

Comment: Added my entire js code. Copy and pasting it into the js portion of your codepen is working for me at the moment.

Comment: Jeff, let me ask you, but why you assigned a value of an empty string again? Number  already has that value.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the multiple variable declarations syntax, but the variable 'number' inside of the event handler function kept evaluating as undefined. I didn't want to remove any of your code and just got the minimum viable working changes in place- obviously refactoring is always a good thing! Do those changes work on your end?

Comment: Apparently my previous variable declarations were wrong so I just stick with  var number = ""; var newNumber = ""; var operator = ""; And it works without a need to declare it again. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

just to display which number is clicked on-

```
var totalNumber = document.getElementById("total");
totalNumber.textContent = "";
document.getElementById("numbers").addEventListener('click', function(e){
    totalNumber.textContent += e.target.innerText;
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but by doing this - number don't store the value under var number. Just displaying. What I'm trying to achieve is that by clicking the number it will store the number and display it, then i click the number again and it becomes new number, after that I'm planning to use operators and parseInt that to get a final value.

Comment: that's different case. You should edit your question.